# Cron Job PHP Script Issue

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a cron job for a URL which contains a simple PHP script (No JavaScript involved). Accessing the URL from browser works flawlessly. But when I use any free cron job service (EasyCron, SetupCron) the job for the same URL gives the following output :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 08:07:45 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Encoding: gzip

```
    <html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d) {
        var e = [];
        d.replace(/(..)/g, function (d) {
            e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
        });
        return e
    }
    function toHex() {
        for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++)e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
        return e.toLowerCase()
    }
    var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"), b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"), c = toNumbers("03550b23010b210056dd8cbb35311f2a");
    document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
    document.cookie = "referrer=" + escape(document.referrer);
    location.href = "http://www.rentely.ga/scrapper.php?ckattempt=1";</script>
<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with
    Javascript support
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: http 200 means everything worked. and i only see javascript but no php in your code sample?

Comment: the concerned file *scrapper.php* does not contain any JavaScript code, simple php html parser and db inserts.

Comment: the whole code is not short enough to fill this comment box..